# How to get Jmeter Version and Java Version dynamically in the dashboard page

Tags: jmeter

Is there any way to get the Jmeter Version and Java Version dynamically in the dashboard page.

I know under user.properties file:

jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title=Your desired title

by manually

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably writing JMeter and Java versions into a .properties file and feeding it to JMeter later on.

1. Add [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) with 1 thread and iteration
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the tearDown Thread Group
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()

   def jmeterVersion = org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getJMeterVersion()
   def javaVersion = System.getProperty('java.version')

   new File('version.properties').write('jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title=' + jmeterVersion + ';' + javaVersion)
   ```
4. That's it, now when you run your JMeter test it will generate *version.properties* file containing JMeter and Java versions as the `jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title` property. Now you can [generate JMeter Reporting Dashboard out of the .jtl file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) like:

   ```
   jmeter -q version.properties -g /path/to/result.jtl -o /path/to/dashboard/folder
   ```

   and you will see JMeter and Java versions instead of default `Apache JMeter Dashboard` text

More information:

- [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Full list of JMeter Command-Line Options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)